# Is the forum structure of stack overflow available for cusomized personal usage

Tags: support

Is it possible to use the question/comment/answer/etc. structure of stack overflow for customized (non-commercial) purposes outside of the stack overflow community?

I am teaching a class on foundations in computer science at a university in Germany, and we provide for our students a forum to discuss lecture-related questions as well as exercises from the tutorials among themselves and with the teaching team. However, the forum is used so frequently that the classic forum structure has become quite confusing. For example, there is no easy way to distinguish good answers from rather unhelpful ones or the very high amount of discussions/comments which do not answer a question. Furthermore, all users are "equal" in this forum meaning that a student cannot distinguish (easily) between answers from other students and answers from the teachers.

I like the stack overflow forum very much, including the reputation-based user evaluation, and I would like to use it (or a similar forum) for the above purpose. Therefore, I would need a personal customized version of the forum which can be used only by our students.

Is this possible/desired? Does someone have experiences in this direction or alternative suggestions?

Comment: See [Stack Exchange clones](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2267)

Comment: Also, don't call it a forum; it is a Q&A site.

Comment: Ok, sorry - didn't mean to offend anyone :-)

Comment: Anyone know why this is downvoted to a negative number?  It's a perfectly good question with an informative answer, isn't it?

Comment: @msouth: That's what I thought! And btw., I managed to build a very nice and highly frequented discussion group based on q2a as suggested in the answer. (http://info2.aifb.kit.edu/qa/index.php)
I'd also like to know why this was such a bad question... Maybe I should have researched better by myself, but starting from nothing, it was not at all obvious.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no option to run the Stack Exchange software in a private setup at the moment. There *are* some experiments by Stack Exchange (the company) with [class-specific sites for EdX](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231208/what-is-story-behind-the-edx-stackexchanges) but I don't think the team plans to make those generally available.

There is a list of Q&A software options you could install locally maintained on Meta Stack Exchange: [Stack Exchange clones](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-exchange-clones)

Comment: That is what I was looking for - I believe we can find there a site suitable for our purpose. Question2Answer looks good at first glance. Thank you!